# What are the Chances to Get a Walnut Tree from Seed that Yields Similar Nuts as its Parent

Tags: seedlings, walnut

I have read that most trees that are grown from seed turn up to be very different than the parent. For example, some [sources](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35691/what-are-the-chances-to-get-an-edible-apple-from-a-tree-grown-from-seed) claim that the chance to get good apples from an apple grown from seed is 1/25. However, I also read that self-fertile trees tend to grow [fairly true to seed](https://pipmagazine.com.au/news/growing-fruit-trees-from-seed/). I would expect that chances to get similar nuts to the nuts of the parent walnut would be much higher than the apple's offsprings. Still, I cound not find any evidence if English walnuts grow partially true to seed or not. I would like to know if someone has some statistics or has conducted an empirical evidence on that.

Comment: Depends what you mean by similar. I am unfamiliar with walnuts, but pecans are very common here and many varieties have been developed ; some larger, some smaller, some thinner shells , but all "similar".

Comment: @blacksmith37, for the walnut I guess the 3 most important qualities are to be with a thinner shell, larger size and to be able to produce generous amount of nuts each year. So, if the parent exhibits these qualities, what are the chances that the child walnut is also like that? (under equal other conditions). I am also interested to know if the chances are higher in comparison with other fruit trees, e.g. cherries and apples, for which there is enough evidence that they do not come true from seed. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect the seeds will produce nuts that are a blend of the parent tree nuts. I have a peach that grew from a pit; it produced fruit very similar to the "mother" tree .