# Are kaki more stable than apple when planting seeds of market's fruits?

Tags: fruit-trees, seeds

From what I read [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22591/how-can-i-grow-seedlings-from-commercial-apples) and [there](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35691/what-are-the-chances-to-get-an-edible-apple-from-a-tree-grown-from-seed?noredirect=1&lq=1), I understand that apple seeds do not easily give of fine edible apples.

How is it now for what I could get from kaki seeds. Does anyone know if it is similar to apple trees when it comes to genetic instability?

I have these seeds from a kaki "Fuyu". Will I be able to grow a tree with tasty fruits?
[image: kaki Fuyu seeds]

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, no, because like apples and many other deciduous fruit trees, the seed, if it's produced at all and is actually fertile rather than sterile, does not come true. Seeds of some persimmon trees may be planted and grown by nurseries for use as rootstocks, with the desired variety being grafted onto the rootstock stem. There's  not much information in this link https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/149306/ but it does at least confirm that the seeds don't come true. The other link I could provide is to a very long and detailed PDF document published by the Agricultural Department of New South Wales, Australia, where it clearly states they do not come true from seed, but the fact its a PDF and so lengthy deterred me from doing so.

Comment: Since the story I heard was that *apples* had unusually high variabiIity in what sprouted from their seeds, I looked it up found a contradictory article which tells how to grow fuyu kaki (persimmons) from seed:  ...   http://homeguides.sfgate.com/plant-fuyu-persimmon-pit-44168.html   ...  That article recommends chilling seeds for 2-3 months at ~40 F, & then *warming* to sprout, & also warns that the seeds have a naturally low germination rate, so work with quite a few at a time...I have *not* tried this myself, but I do recommend further research (beyond Dave's Garden), &/or experimentation.

Comment: @LorelC. yes, I read that article previously, but it did not tell me what I wanted to know,namely, whether the seeds will come true, it doesn't mention that aspect at all. And I discovered elsewhere that they don't, so knowing how to get them to grow and growing them on well is somewhat pointless if you want a particular variety, but  fine if you have lots of space and just want to experiment. Plus the question was asking whether the seedlings were variable or not... so it was necessary to establish whether they came true, or whether they did not.